# Breaking long equations in R documentation

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2

I am trying to write a long equation in the documentation of a function in R.
How can I break it into multiple lines? I tried adding `\cr` into the `\deqn` environment but the check returned me the following error

> LaTeX errors found: ! Misplaced \cr.  \tilde {Var} = \cr 
>                                 \sum _{i \in U} \pi *i \Bigl ( 1 - \frac {n-1}... l.298 ...{Y}{n}\sum*{i\in U} \pi_i^2 \Biggr)^2 }{}

I am writing documentation using `roxygen2`, but I also tried to add `\cr` manually to the `Rd` file and got the same result.

Here is an example of my code without `\cr`

```
#' @details
#'
#' \itemize{
#'     
#' \item Equation:
#'
#'     \deqn{ \tilde{Var} =
#'     \sum_{i \in U} \pi_i \Bigl( 1 - \frac{n-1}{n}\pi_i \Bigr) 
#'     \Biggr( \frac{y_i}{\pi_i} - \frac{Y}{n}  \Biggr)^2
#'     - \frac{n-1}{n^2} \sum_{i \in U} \Biggl( 2\pi_i^3 - \frac{\pi_i^2}{2}
#'     \sum_{j \in U} \pi_j^2 \Biggr)\Biggr( \frac{y_i}{\pi_i} - 
#'    \frac{Y}{n}  \Biggr)^2
#'     + \frac{2(n-1)}{n^3} \Biggl( \sum_{i \in U}\pi_i y_i - \frac{Y}
#'    {n}\sum_{i\in U} \pi_i^2 \Biggr)^2 }{}
#'
#'}
```

and with `\cr`

```
#' @details
#'
#' \itemize{
#'     
#' \item Equation:
#'
#'     \deqn{ \tilde{Var} =
#'     \sum_{i \in U} \pi_i \Bigl( 1 - \frac{n-1}{n}\pi_i \Bigr) 
#'     \Biggr( \frac{y_i}{\pi_i} - \frac{Y}{n}  \Biggr)^2 \cr
#'     - \frac{n-1}{n^2} \sum_{i \in U} \Biggl( 2\pi_i^3 - \frac{\pi_i^2}{2}
#'     \sum_{j \in U} \pi_j^2 \Biggr)\Biggr( \frac{y_i}{\pi_i} - 
#'    \frac{Y}{n}  \Biggr)^2 \cr
#'     + \frac{2(n-1)}{n^3} \Biggl( \sum_{i \in U}\pi_i y_i - \frac{Y}
#'    {n}\sum_{i\in U} \pi_i^2 \Biggr)^2 }{}
#'
#'}
```